# Не находит файл по относительному пути в Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode7

Xcode не видит файл newfile2 в папке проекта (внутри папки лежит сам проект xcodeproj, папка с ресурсами и newfile2) Если указывать абсолютный путь всё работает. Перенёс проект из документов в домашнюю папку пользователя(свою) всё равно не видит newfile2.

Так же пробовал отыскать newfile3 куда пишет если не указывать абсолютный путь. spotlight его не находит( прям не знаю что делать.

Версия Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014), OSX 10.11.4 (15E65)

Код (из книги Кочана):

```
    NSFileManager *fm;
    NSData *fileData;
    fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];


    //читаем файл newfile2 в буфер
        fileData = [fm contentsAtPath:@"newfile2"];
        if(fileData == nil)
            {
            NSLog(@"Чтение файла завершилось неудачей");
            return 1;
            }


    //пишем данные из буфера в файл newfile3
        if ([fm createFileAtPath:@"newfile3" contents:fileData attributes:nil] == NO)
            {
            NSLog(@"Неудаётся создать копию");
            return 2;
            }

        NSLog(@"Копирование успешно завершено");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[NSFileManager defaultManager]` инициализируется в корневом каталоге диска. Если тебе надо использовать файл из проекта, то добавь его в проект и обращайся через метод

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"newfile2" ofType:nil inDirectory:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Все как всегда просто, достаточно было сменить "текущую" папку на папку где лежит файл:

fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fm changeCurrentDirectoryPath:@указываем папку проекта или папку где лежит файл"];